# Dishonest debate tactic name - metaphor to farm, tower?

Tags: metaphors

I can't think of the phrase. I remember the meaning - it's when you claim some very large thing, but then when made to defend it, defend a smaller and more defensible claim that sounds similar. Implicit redefinition of the terms involved may occur.

I remember the metaphor, too - analogizing the big claim to farmland and the small one to a fortified tower. I just can't remember what the words it used were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:
["Motte-and-bailey"](http://slatestarcodex.com/2014/11/03/all-in-all-another-brick-in-the-motte/).

Metaphor and definition:

> The writers of the paper compare this to a form of medieval castle, where there would be a field of desirable and economically productive
>   land called a bailey, and a big ugly tower in the middle called the
>   motte. If you were a medieval lord, you would do most of your economic
>   activity in the bailey and get rich. If an enemy approached, you would
>   retreat to the motte and rain down arrows on the enemy until they gave
>   up and went away. Then you would go back to the bailey, which is the
>   place you wanted to be all along.
>
> So the motte-and-bailey doctrine is when you make a bold,
>   controversial statement. Then when somebody challenges you, you claim
>   you were just making an obvious, uncontroversial statement, so you are
>   clearly right and they are silly for challenging you. Then when the
>   argument is over you go back to making the bold, controversial
>   statement.